# Is there a full fledged browser control for chrome?

Tags: webbrowser-control

We have an application that uses Internet Explorer's browser control to navigate to sites and scrape information by listening to page load events and parsing and accessing the DOM once its ready. I'm looking for a full fledged browser for chrome, similar to the IE [browser control, explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which supports the following

1. Events, like - NavigateComplete, DOM Ready DocumentComplete et al, coming from the browser
2. Traversal and Operations on the DOM
3. Navigations on the Page - click, post et al
4. Cookie Access
5. Message Box and Internet Error Dialog Handling
6. The ability to customize the location where static content, like .css, .axd and .js are cached, to a different location compared to where dynamic conent, like .html are cached.

Comment: Firefox can do that (I'm quite sure), as it's Add-On API is *really* nonrestrictive. Chrome, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Wekitdotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/) project. It may still be early for it but looks like one of the more promising options.